# gem 'pg' can't be loaded only for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems

I am using pg gem pg-0.17.1-x86-mingw32. It is working fine when i am connecting it from my ruby codes.But when i am trying to connect it via rails apps, it gives me an error::
"Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile."

I am gettigng this error at the time of executing:: "rake db:migrate"
after changing the database.yml

My yml looks like::

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: postgres
  host: localhost
  user: postgres
  password: postgre90
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I am using::

```
Rails -4.0.4
Ruby -1.9.3
```

Please help.. I am a newbie in ruby on rails

Comment: Have you got `gem pg` in your GemFile?

Comment: Hi Rich Peck:: can you please provide me the path of the GemFile to look into because i can see 5-6 GemFile here.

Comment: Add the error message here.

Comment: It should be in `app_root/GemFile`

Comment: If you have 5/6 Gemfile's you have serious issues - you only need one

Comment: Its the file called Gemfile inside your app folder, not the Gemfile.lock, you need to include 'gem pg' and run bundle install.

Comment: One application have only one gem file then how can you have 5 and more gem files. @user3322822

Comment: rake aborted!
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile.

Comment: Get bundle install after specified gem in gem file.

Comment: Rich Peck :: actually i was serching the GemFile.lock in the ruby installation folder.. yes i have one GemFile.lock in the app_root folder. but there is no pg gem

Comment: Bharat Soni:: can you please tell me how to add the pg-0.17.1-x86-mingw32 in the GemFile.. can i just write it to the GemFile??

Comment: Hey buddy you don't need to edit or making any changes to the gem lock file.

Comment: just add the gem like gem 'pg' and then bundle install it will install according to application need.

Comment: Bharat Soni:: can you please provide the exact commands with the directory to execute commands..I am running this in windows.i am not getting this.. sorry for the disturbance..please help..

Comment: gem pg bundle install

if i am running this command in the project directory..

Comment: I am getting an error :: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command pg

Comment: you need any tutorial to get update with rails find and read carefully .

Comment: sure.. i am learning only.. i found this in a tutorial.. but stuck in this.. thats why asked..

Comment: I think i got a work around here.. we just need to edit the correct gemfile.. i was actually editing the GemFile.lock but latter when i edited GemFile.file, then the "bundle install"
worked and the postgres db migraton also successfull.

Comment: @Bharat Soni:: is this what you told me to do?? please confirm..

Comment: yes, good you got the point.

Comment: thanx for d prompt reply @Bharat Soni